# An automated algorithm tool for running time

Tags: c++

I am wondering if there is an open source project that can run the algorithm and tell us what the running time is (just need to know the Big-Oh running time).

I know I can do this with hands, but a lot of algorithms are too long or too complex to actually trace the running time.

Thanks.

PS: Mainly for C++ (but it works for more than just C++ would be nice!!)

Comment: I've got a feeling that this reduces to the Halting Problem...

Comment: I've done this before - manually though. Write a script that runs the program a bunch of times with different sizes. And then start curve-fitting it against a bunch of common complexities. Though I will warn that this approach is fundamentally unreliable as run-times can be very chaotic depending on the task.

Comment: @Mysticial: I've done that and found it highly unreliable.  I can get linear and polynomial and exponential equations that all look super close to my data with the same deviations.  :(

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Wow, I haven't seen cases that were THAT bad. In the cases that I did, I was able to distinguish a `O(n log(n)^2)` algorithm from an `O(n log(n)^3)`. But I was testing at gigantic sizes that were well into the asymptotic behavior of the algorithms. I can imagine for small sizes (for where exponential is actually testable), anything can happen as overheads outweigh everything.

Comment: @Mysticial: My algorithm had a bug that caused it to crash when N > ~171.  If I could test bigger numbers I might have done better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's just no way to do this. You'll never know generally what set of `n` you have to test for any given algorithm. For example `sin` and linear will look almost identical at small values of `t` (the input). Exponential can look polynomial in various ranges of input. For other functions, the constant time may make a linear function look sublinear.

The way to figure out the big-oh complexity is to just analyze the algorithm yourself.

Comment: Ah yes, but can you do that in constant time?